# WebAPI 2 XML serialization of an inherited and hidden property

Tags: asp.net, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following style of data structure:

```
class OtherSummary { ... }

class OtherFullData : OtherSummary { ... }

class Summary
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OtherSummary> Stuff { get; set; }
}

class FullData : Summary
{
    // hide the base member because we want full data in this class.
    public new IEnumerable<OtherFullData> Stuff { get; set; }
}
```

In my web api 2 controller, some methods return Summary objects, while others return FullData objects. This all seems to work except that when returning a FullData object, there are two nodes in the XML for the "Stuff" property (edit: if the output is XML - it seems fine in JSON).
One is always empty, so I can only assume this is the hidden base property being serialized?

I am not tinkering with the serialization output from the api in any way.
The controller methods are more or less:

```
public IHttpActionResult Search(string term)
{
    // do the search and map to summary objects ...
    return this.Ok(summaryData);
}
// returns as expected:
<Summary>
    <Name>xyz</Name>
    <Stuff>
        <OtherSummary>...</OtherSummary>
    </Stuff>
</Summary>

public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    // get data and map to a full object ...
    return this.Ok(fullData);
}
// returns with phantom Stuff node:
<Summary>
    <Name>xyz</Name>
    <Stuff />
    <Stuff>
        <OtherFullData>...</OtherFullData>
    </Stuff>
</Summary>
```

I really want this to be as out-the-box as possible, so without getting into writing custom contract resolvers or stuff am I missing something simple that will prevent this? I would have thought that the hidden property would not have been serialized in the first place.

Alternatively I make the summary and full objects separate, although that is quite a bit of duplication going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest generic approach instead:

```
class Summary<T> where T : OtherSummary
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<T> Stuff { get; set; }
}

class FullData : Summary<OtherFullData>
{
}
```

No need to hide...

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting an answer, the project has moved on a bit since I posted the question and testing it out was fairly complicated, but it did work!